# Why can't I insert objects of the class to the multiset?

Tags: c++, class, insert, set, operator-keyword

I have created an Animal class and then a normal function that takes two Animal objects and uses <operator to compare for them to be ordered in the set.  The declaration of the multiset gives no errors but when I try to insert objects of the Animal class to the multiset it gives error. Can you please tell me how I can insert the objects. The code compiles until it hits the last line where objects are inserted to the multiset. Can you please tell me how i can do this?

```
class Animal{

public:
    Animal(std::string, std::string, int);
    std::vector<std::string> achievements;
    int getAge()const {return age;};
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string kind;
    int age;
};

Animal::Animal(std::string n, std::string k, int a): name(n), kind(k), age(a){};

bool compareAge(Animal &a, Animal &b){
    return a.getAge() < b.getAge();
}

int main(){

Animal firstAnimal("Dog", "Mammal", 4);
Animal secondAnimal("Pigeon", "Bird", 1);

std::multiset<Animal, decltype(compareAge)*>animalSet(compareAge);

animalSet.insert({firstAnimal, secondAnimal});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::multiset<Animal, decltype(compareAge)*>animalSet(compareAge);
```

Keys in an associative container are always `const`. This is because once a value is inserted into the associative container its key cannot be changed, therefore it must be `const`ant.

```
bool compareAge(Animal &a, Animal &b){
    return a.getAge() < b.getAge();
}
```

Unfortunately, this comparator takes references to a pair of mutable objects. However, the associative container can only pass reference to `const` objects to the comparator, for the reasons explained above, and in C++ you cannot convert a reference to a `const` object into a reference to a non-`const` object. This should be:

```
bool compareAge(const Animal &a, const Animal &b){
    return a.getAge() < b.getAge();
}
```

You can never go wrong with this rule of thumb in C++: if a function should not be modifying its parameter, the parameter should be `const`.

Comment: thank you, it worked. now how  ca I go about making a multimap in a similar way? I assume the key will be constant but how would I declare such a map?

Comment: In the same, exact way. With the respect to these kind of basic container characteristics, C++ containers tend to implement them in the same way.